# Django won't get https header

Tags: django, apache, docker, nginx, proxy

### Intro

I am building a web app using the latest Django version along with python3.7. The app is dockerized and I plan to deploy with docker-compose. Inside the container, I use nginx to proxy traffic to the application and not expose it directly.  Also, I use apache in server level to proxy traffic to various other containers hosted on the same machine.

In the Django application, I use oauth2 to authenticate to Fitbit Web API and the issue I am facing is that the [django-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is passing the hostname automatically as a `redirect_uri` which now, after a lot of configuration with all those proxies,  works perfectly in HTTP but when I use HTTPS although the app responds normally the `redirect_uri` is still `http` which obviously is not allowed by fitbit and very risky.

Although it is very hard for me to locate in which level the problem occurs I have tried various things but nothing seems to work out.

### What I have tried

#### First

I tried to make my container listen to https request which seemed the most appropriate solution to me but ended getting 502 errors from the Apache.
I tried to find a solution on this by adding some configuration to the virtual host file like

```
#Solution 1
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass / https://localhost:83/ Keepalive=On #Solution 2 (keep alive)
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:83
```

But at last, I found out that it was not an apache issue but that the nginx inside the container was not responding although the traffic was routed to 443 port using HTTPS

#### Second

I tried to route traffic from the apache https to containerd nginx HTTP ( *which does not make so much sense to me* ) which makes the application respond normally but and results the `redirect_uri` error I mentioned above

As you can see I more or less confused and any kind of hint or help could be very useful

## Update 1

The nginx configuration as requested in the comments

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /upload {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your nginx configuration?

Comment: I have added the nginx conf on my post. I generally tried not to add much code inside the post to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the following configuration on the `settings.py`. I also added a control conditional in order to be able to run the container in development.

```
# Was already present before the issue resolved but is also needed
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
# The actual solution
if eval(os.environ.get('DEPLOY', default=False)): 
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
  SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
  SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
  CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```